# How to find exact line of code of memory leaks in Clion c++ using MacOS Monterey 12.0.1 leaks?

Tags: c++, clion, apple-m1, memory-leak-detector

I am using Clion and I want to find a way to find memory leaks on Mac M1. Valgrind is not supported yet.

Let's take this simple code with memory leak:

```cpp
// Program with memory leak

#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

// function with memory leak
void func_to_show_mem_leak()
{
    int* ptr = new int(5);

    // body

    // return without deallocating ptr
    return;
}

// driver code
int main()
{

    // Call the function
    // to get the memory leak
    func_to_show_mem_leak();

    system("leaks SimpleMemoryLeak");
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried using **leaks** :

`leaks *NameOfProccess*`

and I am getting this output:

```
Process 70526 is not debuggable. Due to security restrictions, leaks can only show or save contents of readonly memory of restricted processes.

Process:         SimpleMemoryLeak [70526]
Path:            /Users/USER/Documents/*/SimpleMemoryLeak
Load Address:    0x100ec8000
Identifier:      SimpleMemoryLeak
Version:         ???
Code Type:       ARM64
Parent Process:  clion [39550]

Date/Time:       2021-12-05 23:32:52.942 +0100
Launch Time:     2021-12-05 23:32:52.307 +0100
OS Version:      macOS 12.0.1 (21A559)
Report Version:  7
Analysis Tool:   /usr/bin/leaks

Physical footprint:         945K
Physical footprint (peak):  945K
----

leaks Report Version: 4.0
Process 70526: 208 nodes malloced for 12 KB
Process 70526: 1 leak for 16 total leaked bytes.

    1 (16 bytes) ROOT LEAK: 0x6000003ac030 [16]
```

Is there any way to get the exact line of code where malloc is located? Thanks!

Comment: Your program will probably leak just the same on any other machine. In any case, it helps if you extract a [mcve], for example. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Apple’s “Instruments” GUI-app (included w/Xcode) has some pretty good allocation-tracking features; you might try running your program under that and see what it tells you.

Comment: Also it check to see if you are compiling with debug-info enabled (-g) and optimization disabled (-O0) or at least minimal (-O1)

Comment: Take a look at this video by Mike Shah: Using leaks ... on Mac (https://youtu.be/bhhDRm926qA)